# FFMEG: run code after complete conversion

Tags: php, ffmpeg

There is a code that runs FFMPEG

```
shell_exec($this->config->item('ffmpeg') . ' -i ' . $path . ' ' . $cmd . ' 1>' . $folder . '/log.txt 2>&1 ');
```

And there is the following line, which should, taking into account the peculiarities of the PHP language, work out immediately after `shell_exec`

```
$params = array(
    'status' => 'ready'
);
$result = $this->model->editVideo($video_key, $params);
```

This line simply updates the status of the video in the database

My question is, why doesn’t the further php code work after completion `shell_exec`? What could be the catch?

Comment: What does your log say? Perhaps ffmpeg is waiting for input.

Comment: How can this be checked?

Comment: Open `$folder/log.txt`.

Comment: https://codepen.io/barahten/pen/xxxqWPx - log file

Comment: So it takes 01:48 to transcode, but by default the maximum execution time for PHP scripts is 30 seconds. You should check/enable PHP's error log.

Comment: I put it before `shell_exec` `ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);` and still immediately after transcoding, that is, the line that goes right after  `shell_exec`  does not work. I don’t know what and where to look ...